# Why my LoginActivity goes to onDestroy when dialog for dangerous permissions is shown?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am building an app where I need approve for dangerous permissions in Android 6.0 and above. I watched some tutorials and implemented some of their code into my app. When users goes to my LoginActivity(my launcher Activity is MainActivity but if there is no token, then login activity is shown) and when he clicks button for log in, I must show dialog for permissions, but I want that this dialog is shown on Login activity. But when I click logIn button it exit from app and then dialog is shown. This is my login activity with functions for permissions:

```
 login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String getUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String getPassword = password.getText().toString();

                if (getUsername.length()>0 && getPassword.length()>0 ) {

                    credentials.setUsername(getUsername);
                    credentials.setPassword(getPassword);

                            if (checkPermission()) {
                                allOperations();

                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Permission already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else {

                                requestPermission();
                            }



                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.empty_fields , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

    });
 private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), SEND_SMS);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CALL_PHONE);
        int result3 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result3 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    }
    private void requestPermission() {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, SEND_SMS, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CALL_PHONE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                     boolean locationAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean callAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean smsAccepted = grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean storageAccepted = grantResults[3] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (locationAccepted && callAccepted && smsAccepted && storageAccepted)
                       Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Permission Granted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else {

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Permission denied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                                showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                    requestPermissions(new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, SEND_SMS, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CALL_PHONE},
                                                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }


                break;
        }
    }
    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

Could someone tells me why when I click on logIn button my logIn activity dissaperas and then dialog for permissions is shown?

EDIT: I have no errors in logcat, and my loginActivity goes to onDestroy..

Comment: Check your logcat if some Exception is thrown.Otherwise,I guess this might has something to do with your specified phone or OS.

Comment: No exceptions are thrown...

Comment: Which phone do you use?

Comment: Samsung J5.. but I think that doesn't matter because this same code works when I put him in Main activity, and  also, this code works in another app on the same device

Comment: Please share some more code to enable us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved and my problem was that I put no:history attribute in Manifest!